# Wrong value on print an integer in C

Tags: c

So this is the problem:

Write a program in c which reads the number of plates and the cost of plates, the number of glasses and the cost of glasses and the total cost which customer paid.The program also needs to show the change.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
        float change,total_money;
        float glasses,plates;
        float cost_plates,cost_glasses,total_cost;
        printf("how many glasses you bought: ");//only intenger
        scanf("%f",&glasses);
            while  (glasses<=-1){
                printf("Wrong value type again!\n");
                printf("how many glasses you bought: ");
                scanf("%f",&glasses);
            }   
        printf("how much each glass cost: ");
        scanf("%f",&cost_glasses);
            while  (cost_glasses<=0) {
                    if(cost_glasses==0)
                {
                    printf("Free? ok!\n");
                }
                break;
                printf("Wrong value type again!\n");
                printf("how much each glass cost: ");
                scanf("%f",&cost_glasses);
            }   
        printf("How many plates you bought: "); //only integer
        scanf("%f",&plates);
         while  (plates<=-1) {
            printf("Wrong value type again!\n");
            printf("How many plates you bought: ");
            scanf("%f",&plates);
        }
        printf("how much each plate cost: ");
        scanf("%f",&cost_plates);
                while  (cost_plates<=0) {
                    if(cost_plates==0)
                {
                printf("Free ok!\n");
                }
                break;
                printf("Wrong value type again!\n");
                printf("how much each plate cost: ");
                scanf("%f",&cost_plates);
            }
        total_cost= (cost_glasses * glasses) + (cost_plates * plates);
        printf("how much money you gave:");
        scanf("%f",&total_money);
        while(total_money<=-1) {
            printf("Wrong value type again!\n");
            printf("how much money you gave:");
            scanf("%f",&total_money);
        }
        while(total_money<total_cost) {
            printf("Thief!!! Type again!\n");
            printf("how much money you gave:");
            scanf("%f",&total_money);
        }
        printf("You paid %.2f $ total, the plates and the glasses were costumed %.2f $ so your change was %.2f $",total_money,total_cost,total_money-total_cost);
        return 0;
    }
```

I know this is a bad code, but my problem is (look the comments of the code) when the user types anything else expect an integer I want to print an error.

Comment: The `break` statements need to be inside the `if` statements.

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear to me. Can you give an example of input and describe the problem you have with that input. BTW: Using a `float` for number of plates seems wrong

Comment: if the user types on the question how many glasses you bought for example 2.2 or w  i want to print wrong value type again and i want to loop the question. i want the user types an intenger only and if its not i want to print an error(sorry again for my bad english) i hope u understand me ;D

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I did not catch your question exactly. If a user does not answer **"how many glasses (or plates) you bought"**, then how and where does he/she determine the number of his/her purchased plates?

I'm sure of one thing. No statements and commands are executed after the `break` statement. Perhaps you meant

```
while  (cost_glasses<=0){
        if(cost_glasses==0)
                {
                printf("Free? ok!\n");
                break;
                }
                printf("Wrong value type again!\n");
                printf("how much each glass cost: ");
                scanf("%f",&cost_glasses);
            }
```

**Update**

To filter out the negative or decimal values for the number of plates, use

```
while  (glasses<=-1 || int(glasses)!=glasses){
                printf("Wrong value type again!\n");
                printf("how many glasses you bought: ");
                scanf("%f",&glasses);
            }
```

instead of

```
while  (glasses<=-1){
                printf("Wrong value type again!\n");
                printf("how many glasses you bought: ");
                scanf("%f",&glasses);
            }
```

Comment: i want to print an error when the user types negatives numbers and decimal numbers and i want to loop the question

Comment: I added an update to one part of your code. Hope it help!

Comment: i have an error when i put it... i added an update too to my question!